# Need to pass Formvalues from View to Controller on AjaxSubmit of a Form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

```
I have a Strongly typed View Model
        @model DbRepositories.User
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmuser" })) { 

        Some Controls Goes here..
        <div> <input id="btnsave" type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveUser();" /></div>
        }
```

This is my Javascript File

```
var options = 
{
   success: showResponse  // post-submit callback 
};
function SaveUser() {
$('#frmuser').ajaxSubmit(options);
}
```

and MY Action Method accepting User Object  [HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult AddUser(User Obj)
{
    UserHelper hlp = new UserHelper();
    hlp.AddNewUser(obj);
    return null;
}
```

i am Not getting form field values in my User Obj. How Do i send the form Data to the Controller.
            Please help me where i am Going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Ajax.BeginForm` to submit the form values through ajax.

```
@{
   var ao = new AjaxOptions
            {
              HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post,
              OnSuccess = showResponse,
              OnFailure = ..  
            }
}

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddUser", "Home", ao))
{
   Some Controls Goes here..
   <div><input id="btnsave" type="button" value="Save" /></div>
}
```

You have to make sure to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` or `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`.